# How do you set username and password for secured folders in IIS?

Tags: iis-7, web-hosting

I've been trying to setup the username and password for a production/staging/sandbox website to only allow the client access.

I have the .NET website hosted on IIS with a web hosting company. It is hosted on a sub-domain  i.e. test.domain.com, and I've enabled "Secured Folders" as per this [blog](http://blog.arvixe.com/how-to-enable-secure-folders-in-dotnetpanel/). However, it is unclear on how to set the username and password for "Secured Folders"?

Answer (score 1):

Also refer the other software from the below URL:

http://www.filetransit.com/files.php?name=Troxo

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if your hosting environment is IIS 7, but if that's true then you can implement [URL Authorization](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/142/understanding-iis-70-url-authorization/) to allow access to the authorized users only.